# Debugging Windows Service -- ReVisit (Windows 7)

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, windows-services

Hi there have been lot of discussion on this topic(Debugging Windiows service) Earlier as well https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=debug+windows+service

But am having few problems implementing the same.

- I Tried adding attach process from VS 2008 but the particular .Exe is disabled so am not able to attach
- Also Tried the below code using debugger

  ```
  #if DEBUG
  Debugger.Launch();
  #endif
  ```

Am getting Error when debugger is called `"UnHandled Exception Occured--JIT compiler was launched without any security permissions.To debug run as administrator"`

I have Admin rights for this PC and am using **Windows 7** how can i debug it ?

PS: I can debug making this an Console application. But want to know why the above method fails..Is there a way i can debug as a service ?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly-  start the JIT with proper privileges. i.e. start the service as administrator. You can set username and password for the service to use when starting.

Comment: Ya i tried Specifying username and paswword instead of local account. But still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

When you attach the process the process should be running.  These are the two ways I've used to debug services

1) Add a sleep timer in the beginning of your windows service, run the service, then in vs- Debug->attach to a process

2) Creating and Reading DUMP files (google DebugDiag [v1.2 is the newest?])  It can allow you to look for crashes in threads, memory leaks, cpu usage fluxs. Use WinDbg to read the dump files.